# MAUI ListView Filtering is too slow on Android Phone

Tags: c#, android, database, maui

.Net MAUI, I have a searchbar and a CollectionView (With only 50 CityNames from DB).
Filtering of the collectionview Items on TextChanged property of SearchBar is very slow.
I can't even type properly.
I have tried a lot things like making the calls Async, Converting the CollectionView to ListView etc. but nothing worked.
works okay on the windows app but on android it is giving me hard time.
and my android device is pretty new and powerful, so no issues with the phone.
[image]
Below is the Xaml

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
       <Frame BackgroundColor="MintCream" Padding="10"
              CornerRadius="20">
           <VerticalStackLayout>
               <SearchBar x:Name="FromSearchBar" TextChanged="FromSearchBar_TextChanged" Text="{Binding FromSearchText}" Placeholder="From City" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />            
           </VerticalStackLayout>
       </Frame>
       <CollectionView x:Name="FromColl" ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}" IsVisible="true">
           <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <HorizontalStackLayout Padding="10">
                       <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                              Text="{Binding FullCityName}" 
                              FontAttributes="Bold" />
                   </HorizontalStackLayout>
               </DataTemplate>
           </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
       </CollectionView>
   </StackLayout>
```

C# Code Behind:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ViewModel = new NewItemViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = ViewModel;
    }
    public NewItemViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }


    private void FromSearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var searchBar = (SearchBar)sender;
        ViewModel.Cities = new ObservableCollection<CityList>(CityRepository.GetAllFromDbAsync(searchBar.Text));
        ViewModel.FromListViewVisible = true;
    }
```

Repository For DB:

```
public static List<CityList> GetAllFromDbAsync(string str)
        {
            try
            {
                var rtdb = new RTDatabase();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                    return rtdb.GetItems().Result.Take(50).ToList();
                else
                    return rtdb.GetItems().Result.Where(a => a.CityName.ToLower().StartsWith(str.ToLower())).Take(50).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogError.log("CityRepository.cs - GetAllFromDbAsync - " + ex.Message);
                return new List<CityList>();
            }
        }

public Task<List<CityList>> GetItems()
        {
            return Database.Table<CityList>().ToListAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Why are you doing “new RTDatabase“ on **every query**?

Comment: That's just for instantiating that class. It can be instantiated at class level etc but Currently I am stuck at the slowness, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doing that every time is wasteful.  Retrieving the entire db table every time and then filtering is wasteful.  Either filter in the db query or store the table in memory so you don’t have to repeatedly query it.  And doing some basic profiling to determine where the bottleneck is would also be a good idea.

Comment: I totally agree but there is a single table and that too has only 50 rows. Also i took your suggestion and removed it from the function but its still the same.

Comment: have you done any profiling to determine where the problem is actually occurring?

Comment: First, determine whether the slowness comes from something in Maui, or from GetAllFromDbAsync. This is as easy as making two hardcoded lists of 50 strings, and replacing GetAllFromDbAsync by a method that each time it is called, returns one or the other lists. (Alternating between lists, so the UI has to change.) Is it fast now? If "Yes", then this has nothing to do with Maui.

Comment: I hardcoded the list as well but the slowness stays the same so I believe its coming from MAUI

Comment: Have you tried to run on an Android emulator?

Comment: Yes on emulator as well as on 2-3 different phones.

Comment: Need more details, to confirm whether it is a Maui problem. **Add to question the exact code** that you wrote, to work with hardcoded lists instead of GetAllFromDbAsync. The goal is to have as simple an example as possible, that demonstrates the problem. Ideally, make a new project, with just enough code to build and run and show the problem (using hardcoded lists), then put that in a `public github repo`.

Comment: Also **Add to question** the definition of `ViewModel.FromListViewVisible`. Is that doing some sort of "refresh"? It may be an essential clue as to what is happening. What happens to performance if you comment out `ViewModel.FromListViewVisible = true;`? That line should not be needed for the "hardcoded" test.